# Drop-down box in Django admin does not auto-populate with choices

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models in my models.py file; Genre and AudioTracks. Each track will be assigned a genre; as such, I have defined a ForeignKey relationship. 
My problem is that in the admin view, when i want to add the genre fore each track, I can't select the choices from the combo box. I have to click on the add symbol (i.e. the green +) and then a Genre window pops up and I can then add the genre.

I want to be able to just add a track and select the genre in the little combo box at the bottom.

Here are the images:

[image: I want to be able to see the genre choices instead of clicking "add"]

Second Image:

[image: What happens when I click "add"]
A snippet of my code is below:

```
GENRE_CHOICES =  (
             ('rock', 'Rock'),
             ('jazz/blues', 'Jazz/Blues'),
             ('blues', 'Blues'),
             ('r&b', 'R&B'),
             ('jazz', 'Jazz'),
             ('pop', 'Pop'), 
             ('hip-hop', 'Hip-Hop'),    
             )


def get_upload_path(dirname, obj, filename):
  return os.path.join("audiotracks", dirname, obj.user.username, filename)

def get_audio_upload_path(obj, filename):
  return get_upload_path("audio_files", obj, filename)


class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_choices = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100, unique = True) 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('view_midmentals_genre', None, {'slug':self.slug})

class AudioTrack(models.Model):
  class Meta:
      pass

user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
    related_name = "tracks",
    blank = True,
    null = True
)

added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null = True)
audio_file = models.FileField(_("Audio file"), upload_to=get_audio_upload_path)
title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length="200", null=True)
description = models.TextField(_("Description"), null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 40, unique = True) #so as to have a dedicated page for each category 
genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
```

Please let me know if i need to rephrase my question or title. I was having a hard time putting it into words.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have the + icon because probably you have not added any records to the Genre Model.
Once you add one, the combo box will contain this record.

**But** it seems the you already knows what the Genres are going to be so you can just do this:

```
class AudioTrack(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(..., choices = GENRE_CHOICES)
```

and the combo box will contain the choices you have in the list.

and consider do you choices list like:

```
GENRE_CHOICES = ((0,'Rock'),(1, 'Jazz'),(2,'Hip Hop'))
```

and after:

```
genre = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices = GENRE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: do I still define a foreign key relationship?

Comment: my plan is to eventually be able to display all the tracks under a particular genre in an html template. I'm going to have a page that displays all the tracks under a genre. Will deleting the model still allow me to do this? thanks

Comment: Yes. But if you want maximum flexibility, keep the Genre model, and remove the Genre choices, than add using the + button all the genres you want. The different is that the Genres choices will be records in your DB rather than hard-coded in the python file.